# Import all values from a column if the header matches in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

In Google Sheets is it possible to get all the values in the rows if a column header is the same?

So if I have
[image]

I want to query for "Type" and get the unique values as "Manhole, Overflow, Scour Manhole, Unknown"

If I transpose it I can do something like `=VLOOKUP(B5,Sheet10!1:1000,2,False)` and then have to figure out a way to get it to concatenate all values in subsequent fields of that row but it's better to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command

```
=textjoin(", ", 1, Unique(E2:E7))
```

[`Unique`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en) function returns unique value from the range and [`textjoin`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en) joins the returned value with your provided delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to get all the values in the rows if a column header is the same?

```
=UNIQUE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,          MATCH(E1, 1:1, 0), 4)&":"&
                 ADDRESS(ROWS(A2:A), MATCH(E1, 1:1, 0), 4)))
```

[image: 0]